# regex to extract all digits from a string (not necessarily consecutive)

Tags: regex

(And colons and periods, though I'm sure I can make that modification myself!)

After extracting data from a PDF I have lots of "merged" fields where they've overlapped, such as

```
Joh1n5D:o2d4e.81
```

Which I want to split into

```
John Doe
15:24.81
```

I have a couple hundred of these, so I'm hoping this is possible with a regex - I feel it should be, but can't quite get my head around matching multiple parts from a string and returning them concatenated together?

```
([0-9\:\.])/g
```

Works, but returns separate matches for each character, rather than one string?

Comment: then join the matches into one string. where is the problem?

Comment: I want to be able to paste the input into https://regex101.com or similar and get a usable list of matches in the right-hand panel, so was hoping the joining was possible in the regexp itself

Comment: your text does not contain the sequence "15:24.81" thus it can't be matched by regex. you have to join the individual matches after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex will always return seperate matches, as that's just how regex works. Also, `\d+|[:.]` is probably slightly better as each set of digits will be together.

As for your perdicament, you can use something like `(\d+|[:.])|[\s\S]*?` and substitute with $1 on regex101, like [this](https://regex101.com/r/oV6eT0/1), the added alternation being there to remove all the other characters (though, granted, it leaves a space for each one of them, so it looks odd)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, but it will differ depend on language, you can use two regexes, like: `[\d:.]` and `[^\d:.]` or `[a-zA-Z]` and `[^a-zA-Z]`, an then use a function ocurring in many languages, like `replaceAll` with regex. On Java example:

```
String str = example.replaceAll("[\\d:.]", ""); // result: JohnDode
String time = example.replaceAll("[^\\d:.]", ""); // result: 15:24.81
```

two operations, but no need to using groups, etc.